# fputs overwrites first line is csv

Tags: php, fputs

Here is my code that writes to the CSV. My issue is that it's overwriting the top line of my csv file. Is there some way to go about doing this different? I want to add the new data to the beginning of the csv without overwriting anything that's already there.

```
    // Send Routine 
    $filename="contact.csv";
    $datfile=fopen($filename, 'r+');
            spamcheck($EReply);     
            $ESubject=$Subject;

//          $EMessage = $MsgHeader;
            $EMessage = "Form Submission:\r\n";
            for(reset($FormField); $key=key($FormField); next($FormField)) {
                spamcheck($FormField[$key]);
                $EMessage .= $key.": ".$FormField[$key];
//              $EMessage .= "<br><br>\r\n";
                $EMessage .= "\r\n";
                $datachunk="\"".$FormField[$key]."\",";
                fputs($datfile, $datachunk);
            }
    fputs($datfile, "\r\n");
    fclose($datfile);
```

Comment: why shouldn't it? `r+` = open file for read/write, move file pointer to **START** of file. maybe you want `a+`, which is APPEND, e.g. move to the end of the file.

Comment: I'm sorry - I wasn't clear enough. I want to append the beginning of the file by adding a line at the beginning, not the end. My bad.

Comment: you can't "append" at the start. you have to start a new file, write your new line, then copy the old file's existing data to the end of the new file. You cannot "move" data in a file like you want. And note that this becomes more and more inefficient as the file grows.

Comment: Oh. Well that doesn't make any sense. Why does it work like that?

Comment: it works that way because that is how the filesystem will have to maneuver the data around... but an option is...while this may not work if this is being loaded elsewhere... append to the file, then when reading it in (assuming PHP) just reverse your loop

Comment: fputs is a pencil. you put the pencil at the start of the file, and started writing. but computers aren't a piece of paper that you can just slide around and cut/paste.

Comment: @MarcB That's a very nice analogy. I guess I just assumed that it would work this way because if you start typing at the beginning of a text file, it automatically inserts where your cursor is and moves everything to the right, ya know?

Comment: a wordprocessor is nothing like the underlying file structure.